# Arraylist implementation in C

Tags: c, linked-list

My first language is Java, now I am trying to implement Arraylist using C language for all data types, using void*. Here is my code.

The usage.

```
#include "pk_arraylist_int.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Arraylist myArray = newArraylist();
    list_int_add(&myArray, 0, 10);
    list_int_add(&myArray, 0, 20);
    list_int_add(&myArray, 0, 30);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i != list_size(&myArray); i++) {
        printf("[%d] -> %d\n", i, list_int_get(&myArray, i));
    }
    return 0;
}

int list_int_get(Arraylist* list, int index) {
    Node* reader = list_get(list, index);
    return (int)(int*)(reader->value);
}

void list_int_set(Arraylist* list, int index, int value) {
    int* pointer = &value;
    list_set(list, index, pointer);
}

void list_int_add(Arraylist* list, int index, int value) {
    int* pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    pointer = &value;
    list_add(list, index, pointer);
}
```

and here is the arraylist.c

```
#include "pk_arraylist.h"

Arraylist newArraylist() {
    Arraylist temp;
    temp.root = NULL;
    return temp;
}

Node* _element(Arraylist* list, int index) {
    Node* reader = list->root;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i != index; i++) {
        reader = reader->next;
    }
    return reader;
}

int list_size(Arraylist* list) {
    int size = 0;
    Node* reader = list->root;
    while (reader != NULL) {
        reader = reader->next;
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

bool list_isEmpty(Arraylist* list) {
    if (list->root == NULL) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void* list_get(Arraylist* list, int index) {
    Node* reader = _element(list, index);
    return reader->value;
}

void list_set(Arraylist* list, int index, void* value) {
    Node* reader = _element(list, index);
    reader->value = value;
}

void list_add(Arraylist* list, int index, void* value) {
    int size = list_size(list);
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (index < 0) {
        return;
    } else if (size == 0) {
        list->root = newNode;
    } else if (index == 0) {
        newNode->next = list->root;
        list->root = newNode;
    } else if (index >= size) {
        Node* left = _element(list, index - 1);
        left->next = newNode;
    } else {
        Node* left = _element(list, index - 1);
        Node* right = _element(list, index + 1);
        left->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = right;
    }
}

void list_remove(Arraylist* list, int index) {
    int size = list_size(list);
    if (index == 0) {
        Node* garbage = list->root;
        Node* right = garbage->next;
        free(garbage);
        list->root = right;
    } else if (index == size - 1) {
        Node* left = _element(list, index - 1);
        Node* garbage = left->next;
        free(garbage);
        left->next = NULL;
    } else if (0 < index && index < size - 1) {
        Node* left = _element(list, index - 1);
        Node* garbage = left->next;
        Node* right = garbage->next;
        free(garbage);
        left->next = right;
    }
}

void list_clear(Arraylist* list) {
    while (list_size(list) != 0) {
        list_remove(list, 0);
    }
}
```

and also the arraylist.h

```
#ifndef _PK_ARRAYLIST
#define _PK_ARRAYLIST

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Node {
    void* value;
    struct Node* next;
};
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Arraylist {
    Node* root;
};
typedef struct Arraylist Arraylist;
Arraylist newArraylist();

Node* _element(Arraylist* list, int index);

int list_size(Arraylist* list);
bool list_isEmpty(Arraylist* list);

void* list_get(Arraylist* list, int index);
void list_set(Arraylist* list, int index, void* value);
void list_add(Arraylist* list, int index, void* value);

void list_remove(Arraylist* list, int index);
void list_clear(Arraylist* list);

#endif
```

I was expecting the array to be 30, 20, 10. However outputting the array list I saw 30, 30, 30.

I think the same memory address is being used each time. I suspect that the three elements of the linked list all store the same address.

Problem is how do I solve it? Is there a way for the program to allocate new memory blocks for new data? instead of overwriting the same memory block every time?

I am new to C, any help appreciated thank you.

Comment: Uh, isn't the point of `ArrayList` *not* to use a linked list? I thought it was using the List interface on to of an array to get O(1) performance for common operations (at the cost of not being able to grow/shrink).

Comment: here is problem:    pointer = &value; you replace just allocated pointer with address your local variable. change on *pointer = value;

Comment: I just want to try making an array which can change size. But yes, my implementation is not efficient at all.

Comment: AnatolyS thanks a lot

Comment: can u put it in answers? I will mark it as answer. Thank you very much

Comment: @AnatolyS An array that can change size would be implemented using `realloc()` in C, not a linked list, that's not an array since you only ever have *one* element per list entry.

Comment: @unwind: thanks cap, but how does it relate to me?

Comment: @AnatolyS Doh, it doesn't, wrong @. Sorry.